# wso2 esb authenticate webservice called inside the flow

Tags: wso2-esb

I'w defining a flow in wso2 esb, in this flow
1)I receive a soap message from an external salesforce (salesforce1)
2)I send the same message to another salesforce (salesforce2)

salesforce 1 and 2 are associated with different account so when making the call in 2) I have to request a sessionid for salesforce soap api and use it to make the call.
What is the suggested way to implement this scenario?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Salesforce connector](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/fbb433b5-4d74-4064-84c2-e4b23c531aa2) to connect Salesforce API.Use the logout method to invalidate the session for the first Salesforce call and then use init method with Salesforce2 credentials to connect with 
Salesforce2. Find more details [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Salesforce+Connector+Operations#ConfiguringSalesforceConnectorOperations-LoggingoutofSalesforce).

```
<salesforce.query configKey="SFConfig1">
    <batchSize>200</batchSize>
    <queryString>select id,name from Account</queryString>
</salesforce.query>
<salesforce.logout/>
<salesforce.create configKey="SFConfig2">
    <allOrNone>0</allOrNone>
    <allowFieldTruncate>0</allowFieldTruncate>
    <sobjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc">{//sfdc:sObjects}</sobjects>
</salesforce.create>
```

Comment: Thanks kesavan
unfortunately I have to interact with a custom webservice deployed on salesforce. This ws uses the soap api, The input of my service is the soap message I have to send to salesforce2, I just need to modify it to include the sessionid that I previously obtain from salesforce2.